# Slicing a Django queryset without retrieving everything from the database

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Lets say, I want the first 12 elements from a Django queryset. Now I could easily do this as follows:

```
queryset = Content.objects.all()[:12]
```

This works, but I am retrieving every single Content from my database. Is there a better way to do this? I am thinking something that only retrieves the first 12 items from the queryset from the database.

Thanks.

Comment: No you're not. That *is* the thing that only retrieves the first 12 items from the database. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, that is the correct limit syntax for the django ORM. If you open up a shell and try it out you will notice what it is doing.

```
>>> queryset = Content.objects.all()[:12]
>>> queryset
<QuerySet [...]>
>>> str(queryset.query)
'SELECT * FROM "content" LIMIT 12'
```